# How to make jQuery animation smoother

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Currently, the animation [on my website](http://uat.priworks.com/SustainGreen/climate-change#howgreen) looks a bit jittery. Ideally, I would like the page to load, wait a few seconds, then smoothly anchor to `#howgreen` and then open the accordion.

In this webpage ([URL](http://uat.priworks.com/SustainGreen/climate-change#howgreen)), it anchors to `#howgreen` and the jQuery below looks for `#howgreen` in the URL and if it exists it opens/triggers/clicks it to open the accordion (`#howgreen-text`).  How can I delay the animation or make the animation on my website work more smoothly?

```
$("#howgreen").click(function () {
    $(this)
        .parent()
        .children('#howgreen-text')
        .animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 'slow', function () {
            if ($(this).parent().children('#howgreen-text').css('display') == 'block') {
                $(this)
                    .parent()
                    .children('#howgreen')
                    .addClass("work-main-bar-active");
            } else {
                $(this)
                    .parent()
                    .children('#howgreen')
                    .removeClass("work-main-bar-active");
            }
        });
});
/* Anchor Open Accordions */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        if (document.location.href.indexOf('#howgreen') > -1) {
            $('#howgreen')
                .trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I added document .ready and still not very smooth:

Comment: ready will wait until the `dom` is ready, `load` will wait until everything has loaded :D sweeetttttt

Comment: can u put code on js fiddle , i want to test it, if you need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen for the page load event and then wrap the click trigger in a setTimeout like so

```
/* Anchor Open Accordions */   
$(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            if ( document.location.href.indexOf('#howgreen') > -1 ) {
                $('#howgreen').trigger('click');
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways come to my head, and I think you should use a combination of the two. So I'll point you in the direction :)

First off you have the jQuery function [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and this will do as the name suggests, it will delay animations . So this will only apply to this part of your code

```
 $(this).parent().children('#howgreen-text').animate({
    height: 'toggle'
 }
```

So you could easily do this:

```
$(this).parent().children('#howgreen-text').delay(1000).animate({
    height: 'toggle'
}
```

Which will now delay for 1 second.

However I think you should use a better approch and wait until your assests are loaded and then run your JS with:

```
window.onload = function(){..}
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a jump at the start and end of the collapse that's caused by the padding on the element itself appearing and disappearing all at once.

The solution is to create a child element of the div and add the padding to it.

Currently, you have:

```
.happening-main-text {
    /* other styles */
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
```

You should wrap ALL the children of `.happening-main-text` in another `<div>...</div>` and move the above style to it:

```
.happening-main-text > div {
    padding: 30px 0px 0px 30px;
}
```